# No implementation for OWrites and Reads was bound in Scala Play app

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I have multiple model classes which all share the same properties. For that very reason, I created a trait, e.g.:

```
trait Player extends Temp {

  val gameId: BSONObjectID

  val personalDetails: abc.PersonalDetails // <- comes from shared library

}

case class FootballPlayer(var _id: Option[BSONObjectID] = None,
                         gameId: BSONObjectID,
                         personalDetails: abc.PersonalDetails,
                         var created: Option[DateTime] = None,
                         var updated: Option[DateTime] = None
                        ) extends Player

case class VideogamePlayer(var _id: Option[BSONObjectID] = None,
                         gameId: BSONObjectID,
                         personalDetails: abc.PersonalDetails,
                         var created: Option[DateTime] = None,
                         var updated: Option[DateTime] = None
                        ) extends Player
```

All of these models, have as a companion object `play.api.libs.json.Reads` and `play.api.libs.json.OWrites` defined.

For example:

```
object FootballPlayer {

  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
  import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
  import play.api.libs.json._
  import reactivemongo.play.json.BSONFormats.BSONObjectIDFormat

  implicit val footballPlayerReads: Reads[FootballPlayer] = (
    (__ \ "_id").readNullable[BSONObjectID].map(_.getOrElse(BSONObjectID.generate)).map(Some(_)) and
      (__ \ "gameId").read[BSONObjectID] and
      (__ \ "personalDetails").read[abc.PersonalDetails] and
      (__ \ "created").readNullable[DateTime].map(_.getOrElse(new DateTime())).map(Some(_)) and
      (__ \ "updated").readNullable[DateTime].map(_.getOrElse(new DateTime())).map(Some(_))
    ) (FootballPlayer.apply _)


  implicit val sharedPersonalDetailsWrites: Writes[abc.PersonalDetails] = abc.PersonalDetails.sharedPersonalDetailsWrites

  implicit val footballPlayerWrites: OWrites[FootballPlayer] = (
    (__ \ "_id").writeNullable[BSONObjectID] and
      (__ \ "gameId").write[BSONObjectID] and
      (__ \ "personalDetails").write[abc.PersonalDetails] and
      (__ \ "created").writeNullable[DateTime] and
      (__ \ "updated").writeNullable[DateTime]
    ) (unlift(FootballPlayer.unapply))

}
```

Now I want to store them in different collections, but I want to have only one DAO, so I implemented the following:

```
trait PlayerDAO[T <: Player] {

  def findById(_id: BSONObjectID)(implicit reads: Reads[T]): Future[Option[T]]

  def insert(t: T)(implicit writes: OWrites[T]): Future[T]

}

class MongoPlayerDAO[T <: Player] @Inject()(
                                           playerRepository: PlayerRepository[T]
                                         ) extends PlayerDAO[T] {

  def findById(_id: BSONObjectID)(implicit reads: Reads[T]): Future[Option[T]] = playerRepository.findById(_id)

  def insert(t: T)(implicit writes: OWrites[T]): Future[T] = playerRepository.insert(t).map(_ => t)

}
```

Then, I have the following repository:

```
class PlayerService[T <: Player] @Inject()(playerDAO: PlayerDAO[T])(implicit reads: Reads[T], writes: OWrites[T]) {

  def findById(_id: BSONObjectID): Future[Option[T]] = playerDAO.findById(_id)


  def save(t: T): Future[T] = playerDAO.save(t)

}
```

My module looks as follows:

```
class PlayerModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

  def configure() {
    bind[PlayerDAO[FootballPlayer]].to[MongoPlayerDAO[FootballPlayer]]
    bind[PlayerDAO[VideogamePlayer]].to[MongoPlayerDAO[VideogamePlayer]]
    // ...
    ()
  }
}
```

And in my Play controller I inject the following:

```
import models.FootballPlayer._
import models.VideogamePlayer._ 

class PlayerController @Inject()(
                                 val messagesApi: MessagesApi,
                                 footballPlayerService: PlayerService[FootballPlayer],
                                 videogamePlayerService: PlayerService[VideogamePlayer]
                               ) extends Controller with I18nSupport
```

However, unfortunately, I get the following exception:

> 1) No implementation for
>   play.api.libs.json.OWrites was bound. 2) No
>   implementation for play.api.libs.json.OWrites
>   was bound. 3) No implementation for
>   play.api.libs.json.Reads was bound. 4) No
>   implementation for play.api.libs.json.Reads
>   was bound.

How can I fix this?

Comment: 1. The definitions of `OWrites` & `Reads` are not indicated. 2. Using `var` in `case class` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: `OWrites` & `Reads` are defined in the corresponding companion object and imported in `PlayerController`.

Comment: Can you post how you have defined OWrites & Reads in companion object?

Comment: @SumeetSharma please see my updated question.

Comment: @JohnDoe can you share your playerrepository definition?

Comment: @JohnDoe Check my edit.

Comment: @JohnDoe have you managed to solve this issue? I now have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it might not be able to find the implicit context when the dao injections are made. Try including implicits in the AbstractModule where you define your bindings.

**EDIT**

Check my solution on git. [Here](https://github.com/sumeetmi2/stackQASolution)

I have tried to emulate whatever you are trying to do and its working fine.

I am not quite sure what is the problem with your current code as I dont have access to the entire code, but I think it has something to do with the application searching for OWrites and Reads implicit for `Player` rather than `FootballPlayer` or `VideoGamePlayer`

Comment: What about the class MongoPlayerDao..can you try adding the implicit def there?

Comment: I appreciate your help! Thanks! Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. The only difference I can see is that I am using one single `PlayerRepository` instead of `VideoGameMongoRepo` and `FootballMongoRepo`. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: That's why I am missing the first two lines in the `CustomModule` and only have ` bind(classOf[PlayerDAO[FootballPlayer]]).to(classOf[MongoPlayerDAO[FootballPlayer]])` and `bind(classOf[PlayerDAO[VideoGamePlayer]]).to(classOf[MongoPlayerDAO[VideoGamePlayer]])`, this will give me the following error:  `repositories.app.PlayerRepository<T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.`

Comment: By using Named dependency for PlayerRepository[VideoGamePlayer] and default injection for PlayerRepository[FootballPlayer] you can make it work. Check I have done that and it works. I think thats what you are trying to do. You may also look into TypeLiteral which is used for injection of generic types. I couldnt make it work but that is something you can look into.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to inject the (de)serializer, while you can just give them as implicit parameter for your class:

```
class PlayerService[T <: Player](implicit reads: Reads[T], writes: OWrites[T]) @Inject()(playerDAO: PlayerDAO[T])
```

or even simpler (to write, but it has strictly the same meaning):

```
class PlayerService[T <: Player: Reads: OWrites] @Inject()(playerDAO: PlayerDAO[T])
```

Since `Reads[T]` and `OWrites[T]` are not implemented as modules, Guice isn't able to inject them properly. However, they can still be normal parameters for your class.

Comment: None of the approaches you suggested works. When using the first one I get the following compile error: `';' expected but '@' found.` and when using the second one, I get the same result as before: `No implementation for play.api.libs.json.OWrites was bound` etc.